# npm WARN deprecated source-map-resolve@0.6.0: See https://github.com/lydell/source-map-resolve#deprecated

Tags: reactjs

When I create React app useing "npx create-react-app my-app" I reserved this warning. how can I solved this issue. can some one help me?

```
npm WARN deprecated source-map-resolve@0.6.0: See 
https://github.com/lydell/source-map-resolve#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated svgo@1.3.2: This SVGO version is no longer 
supported. Upgrade to v2.x.x.

added 1420 packages, and audited 1421 packages in 45s

185 packages are looking for funding
run `npm fund` for details

6 high severity vulnerabilities

To address all issues (including breaking changes), run:
npm audit fix --force

Run `npm audit` for details.
```

Answer (score 1):

To resolve this problem, use the following command to fix audits and bugs `npm audit fix --force`

Answer (score -2):

```
npm install source-map-resolve
```

Comment: Please read [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). While this code block may answer the OP's question, this answer would be much more useful if you explain how this code is different from the code in the question, what you've changed, why you've changed it and why that solves the problem without introducing others.